# DELL XPS 2720 Faint Grid Pattern on a screen

Tags: display, dell-xps

Got a brand new DELL XPS 2720 the screen is phenomenal but on a light background (say with notepad on a full screen) I can see a faint grid pattern - light gray horizontal & vertical lines forming the gird filling the whole screen with about one centimeter step. I think the brightness level is set to max or close to it.

I saw a few people complaining about the issue here:
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/19596883

On a separate account the screen is flickering badly like a 60Ghz monitor from early 90s. I'm very confused by this after reading a few 5star reviews from the reputable press. A colleague of mine said the grid effect is immanent to this type of screens (touch IPS) when brightness is maxed out and is got to do with IPS panels technology and touch sensors.

Could anyone shed some light on the issue - is it worth trying to replace the unit or I should chase up for a refund.

Comment: A photo would help. (If you do not have the reputation to edit pictures into your post, put it on an image hosting site and add the link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest replacing the unit.
By the looks of the link you've sent it's just a faulty unit.

"Yes, my replacement XPS did not have grid lines.  The new one has a very sharp screen and has been great so far."

Comment: or I understood that it is "unfixable" while I still generally like it...